# Android auto - how to install DHU on MAC dependencies with homebrew

Tags: android, homebrew, android-auto

Per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/auto/start/index.html) on android auto i should be installing these dependencies to get the desktop head unit to work:

$ sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 libportaudio2 libpng12-0

but im not on debian, im using mac, so i was trying to use homebrew. Whats the command i can use to install all of these in one shot ?

and when i try to install using homebrew for example, i get the following error:

```
brew install libsdl2-2.0-0
Error: No available formula with the name "libsdl2-2.0-0"
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

From the docs it says the following but i cant do it because i dont have apt-get and brew isn't working:

> If you are running the DHU on Linux, you must also install the
>   portaudio, libpng, sdl2, and sdl2_ttf libraries. The procedure to do
>   this varies depending on your Linux distribution. For example, on
>   Debian-derived Linux distributions, you can install the libraries with
>   this command:
>       $ sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 libportaudio2 libpng12-0

can i skip this step ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can i skip this step ?

Yes, you can skip it.

This step is only for Linux machine, I can confirm that the Desktop Head Unit works on my mac (OSX 10.11.1) without the need to install these packages.